# Installing Ubuntu Wubi why on earth does Firewall complains?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Using
http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer
Firewall asks to authorize pyrun ? Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the correct answer to your question but it could be one....
It could be because python uses an internal server for all its handling .... When I use python sometimes I get an error that the internal server is not responding..... So it could be that the firewall is complaining for the same for pyrun.....

Answer (score 0):

wubi checks the local ISO file against the one on Ubuntu's servers, and if the local ones are out of date, downloads them. Since the installer tries to make a network connection, Firewall complains.

Comment: I have succesfully installed without giving authorization so for me that's weird.